# Why CSS3 is not supporting vertical center (directly)?

Tags: css

One very common question on CSS is how to vertically center an element. With CSS3 being able to do so many special effect, why they are not including the vertically center function into CSS3?

I don't believe it is a difficult function to add if even a beginner developer can make a function to center things with javascript. And with so many hacks for different situations, it is clear that with CSS alone it is possible to center things vertically. So maybe there are other reasons that they decide not to make it a standard property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because how layout is performed with CSS — CSS is predominantly arranging items on the x-axis, like how 100% width works as expected but not 100% height. This is likely due to the possible "calculation/logic loop" that happens as width is dependent on height and vice versa, so **one axis must always be prioritized** when it comes to calculation.

Extra info by [@BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock):

> The x-axis thing has to do with the natural flow of text in a
>   document. Remember that the Web started off as a series of pages, so
>   HTML and CSS were originally built around this fundamental premise -
>   it has since evolved into an application platform, but the legacy is
>   still there. Flexbox is the CSS3 way to vertically center boxes - the
>   only issue is cross-browser support, but since the question is about
>   CSS3 anyway, that's to be expected.

Similarly, in terms of dictating alignment, horizontal alignment is easy because the width of an element is often implicitly or explicitly stated, like how a block element automatically has a implicit width of 100% unless otherwise stated, allowing for easy calculation of a center position along the horizontal axis.

However, this does not work for the case of vertical alignment, where often than not the vertical dimension is dependent on the amount, length and size of the content. In the case where vertical height is explicitly stated, this can actually be easily done:

1. by using the **CSS flexbox** method

   - The good: standards compliant and very simple, dimension of element of interest does not have to be fixed
   - The bad: lack of extensive cross-browser support, but [appears very promising today](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.box > .content {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">I am centered</div>
</div>
```

---

2. by using **absolute positioning and CSS transforms**

   - The good: extensive cross-browser support, dimension of element of interest does not have to be fixed
   - The bad: fuzzy text rendering (occasionally) due to sub-pixel translation

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relatve;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.box > .content {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">I am centered</div>
</div>
```

---

3. by using **absolute positioning and negative margins**

   - The good: extremely straightforward
   - The bad: dimension of element of interest MUST be fixed

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.box > .content {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">I am centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The x-axis thing has to do with the natural flow of text in a document. Remember that the Web started off as a series of pages, so HTML and CSS were originally built around this fundamental premise - it has since evolved into an application platform, but the legacy is still there. Flexbox is *the* CSS3 way to vertically center boxes - the only issue is cross-browser support, but since the question is about CSS3 anyway, that's to be expected.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for supplementing with extra info :) but don't you agree that it also has something to do with the paradox of a bi-axial calculation issue? You can't auto width and auto height without explicitly declaring one dimension first :)

Comment: In "Safari" on "Mac, iPhone" can still be a problem with center - this may help "-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translateZ(0px);".

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The first part is enough for answering the question already, but the later information is great and definitely worth reading.